A symmetric inequality involving product of three variables
Let $a, b,c \ge 0, ab + bc + ca + abc = 4$. Find the minimum of $S = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$.
My guess is that $S$ attends its minimum at $b = c = 2, a = 0$ and the other permutation of $(2, 2, 0)$, but I have no idea to proceed from that.
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Inspired by Inequality with $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$ on AoPS: Define
$$
 x = \frac{a}{a+2} \, , \, y = \frac{b}{b+2} \, , \, z = \frac{c}{c+2} \, .
$$
Then $x+y+z = 1$ and
$$
\begin{align}
 S &= \sqrt{\frac{2x}{1-x}} + \sqrt{\frac{2y}{1-y}} + \sqrt{\frac{2z}{1-z}} \\
&= \sqrt 2 \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\right)\\
&\ge \sqrt 2 ( 2x + 2y + 2z) \quad\text{(AM-GM inequality)}\\ 
&= 2 \sqrt 2 \, .
\end{align}
$$
Equality holds exactly if each of $x, y, z$ is $0$ or $1/2$, that is if $(x, y, z)$ is a permutation of $(1/2, 1/2, 0)$, which means that $(a, b, c)$ is a permutation of $(2, 2, 0)$ (just as you suspected).

Thank you very much, Martin. I think the last term should be $z =\dfrac{c}{c+2}$. It seems that people can't solve this without knowing this genius replacement.

@anonimo: Thanks, typo fixed!
